# Interpreting one-class SVM

Tags: svm, anomaly-detection

I am new to SVM (one-class) and was practically investigating it. Got some weird result that I can not explain. Let me demonstrate by some small reproducible code and visualization:

```
from sklearn.svm import OneClassSVM 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

training_data = np.random.normal(2,.5,(10000,1))
###testing data###
Y1=np.random.normal(5,1,(1000,1))
Y2=np.random.normal(4,1,(1000,1))
Y3=np.random.normal(3,1,(1000,1))
```

Fitting model

```
clf = OneClassSVM(gamma='auto').fit(training_data)
```

getting score for each data point

```
pred_training_score=clf.score_samples(training_data)
pred_y1_score=clf.score_samples(Y1)
pred_y2_score=clf.score_samples(Y2)
pred_y3_score=clf.score_samples(Y3)
```

getting prediction###

```
pred_training=clf.predict(training_data)
pred_y1=clf.predict(Y1)
pred_y2=clf.predict(Y2)
pred_y3=clf.predict(Y3)
```

####visualize the prediction on training data

```
df=pd.DataFrame(np.array([list(range(len(training_data))),training_data.reshape(-1),pred_training,pred_training_score]).T)
df.columns=['counter','values','labels','score']
fig = px.scatter(df, x="counter", y="values", color="labels",hover_data=["score"])
fig.show()
```

####training data visualization output
[image]

####Visualize testing data1 (with mean 5)

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(np.array([list(range(len(Y1))),Y1.reshape(-1),pred_y1,pred_y1_score]).T)
df1.columns=['counter','values','labels','score']
fig = px.scatter(df1, x="counter", y="values", color="labels",hover_data=["score"])
fig.show()
```

####testing data (mean 5) visualization output
[image]

This is great. Because I trained with data with mean`2` and test with mean 5 and almost all test data has been classified with anomaly `(label: -1)`.

The visualization of training data says that a soft margin has been computed and labeled data points near 2 as normal and other are abnormal/anomaly.

Now the interesting thing happens if I increase the spread of the data-points by increasing the standard deviation. So lets increase that and train again:

```
training_data = np.random.normal(2,1,(10000,1))
```

Now visualize the labeling of the training data:
[image]

The data points which are very close to 2 has been classified as anomaly. Why is that?

This gets worse if I increase the SD again:
training_data = np.random.normal(2,1.5,(10000,1))
and the visualization:
[image]

Could you please explain this type of behavior?